# Working on For Each Array

Tags: c

I'm a newbie on programming, i'm confused with arrays, how do you guys understand the line says box[rows][cols] = x++;   we know that x=1, so in this statement means box[0][0] = 2; because of x++? when i printf box[row][cols] giving me a value of 1, why is it 1 when we set it as box[rows][cols]= x++; which should be 2 cause we set x=1 then x++ right?

```
int box[2][2], rows, cols, x, i, j;

for(i=1; i<2; i++)
{
    for( j=1; j<2; j++)
    {
       box[rows][cols]= x++;
       printf("%d", box[rows][cols]);  
    }
}
```

Comment: a = x++ assigns the value of x to a and after that adds 1 to x. To do it vise versa you could use ++x

Comment: It's undefined bahaviour, because `x`, `rows`, and `cols` were never initialized, so no one can tell you why it behaves any way at all.

Comment: x is assigned as 0 by default, at least in some compilers.

Comment: @sashkello Not if it's on the stack (IE. not a global)

Comment: aha, I guess user2472887 did assign 1 to it, otherwise where else would it come from?

Comment: @sashkello It's undefined, so it could come from anywhere.

Comment: @Paulpro Yep, true... Anyway, the question is duplicate to lots of other similar questions and certainly the variable should be initialized in such case and there is more than enough info on x++ expression already...

Comment: There's so much wrong with this code it's hard to know where to begin. You start i and j at 1 and each 'loop' executes only once, so box[1][1] would be the only element to be assigned to. At least it would be, if you actually used i and j instead of rows and cols which are never assigned to or used in your loops. x is never initialized as others have pointed out.

Comment: Updated question title to actually reflect the question

Comment: @user2472887: Your code does not seem to make sense. Values of `rows` and `cols` are not initialized. What are the values of `rows` and `cols`? Why did you expect `box[rows][cols] = x++` to affect `box[0][0]`? You have cycles for `i` and `j`, which suggests that you probably planned to access `box[i][j]`. Yet you access `box[rows][cols]` with some unknown indices. No wonder the code prints nothing meaningful.

Answer (score 6):

You need to understand that there is a post increment and pre increment versions to the operator `++` and `--`. In your case the statement `box[rows][cols]= x++;` uses the post increment operator which updates the value of x after assignment.

Try `box[rows][cols]= ++x;` and you will get the expected output of `2`.

Also in your code you need to initialize the two variables `rows` and `cols` are uninitialized. So change the loop as follows,

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    for( j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
       box[i][j]= x++;
       printf("%d", box[j][j]);  
    }
}
```